# Ruby + QT4; how to start

Tags: ruby, qt4

trying to add QtRuby support on my gentoo linux..
i dont find any qt gem in repository
download qt4-qtruby
but cmake fall.. 
please say right way to setup..

Comment: This seems to be a gentoo problem. You better ask at bugs.gentoo.org

Comment: How does cmake fail? Do you have any specifics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to install qt4ruby from portage:

emerge -av kdebindings-ruby

ebuild name was probably changed from qt4-qtruby to kdebindings-ruby but I don't now why.